# Bay Area Synthetic Network node/line coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, network, network-dataset, distribution

I just started working with the [Bay Area Synthetic Network](https://egriddata.org/dataset/bay-area-synthetic-network) and was wondering if this dataset has location (lat/lon) information. I have visualized the files with QGIS, but when it comes to exporting the data, I have not found a solution to obtain exact locations.

[image]
I understand this data is synthetic, so I was wondering if it has any real data for coordinates or the node location is with respect to other nodes.

Comment: @oxj are you looking to perform analysis on the data, or are you looking for the XY coordinates of the features you're looking at in QGIS?

Comment: @DPSSpatial  I guess my comment never posted. I am trying to obtain XY coordinate information and edge information from the nodes. I am new to QGIS, so what I did was I loaded the layers, changed the coordinate system, and used the reference system EPSG:4326 - WGS 84. When I check the coordinates, they take me to oceans, antartica, so I think my reference system is wrong. I guess my question would be how to extract the correct coordinates belonging to the Bay Area in California?

Comment: @PolyGeo I added a snapshot of the network viewed in QGIS. I've work with real distribution networks but in JSON format and they had lat, lon information. Not sure about this network since it is synthetic

Comment: @PolyGeo I saw this and applied it as the coordinate reference system and it gave me something reasonable https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201486/choosing-map-projections-specifically-for-san-francisco-bay-area

Comment: @oxj OK I had the same problem - first the coordinate system must be set correctly... this *should* draw in the bay area, correct? Do you see in the documentation a spatial reference / coordinate system referenced? I don't think 4326 or CA State Plane work.

Comment: @oxj what coordinate system did you end up using?

Comment: @DPSSpatial this seems to have done it, I updated the image. Using NAD_1983_2011_UTM_Zone_10N

Comment: @oxj ok that works. So you're now looking for the LAT/LON of the data? What are you planning on doing with the data. The geometry is stored in the shapefile, but can be analysed/processed through QGIS tools. Or, a system like PostGIS has spatial functions to work on that geometry as well. So what is it you're eventually trying to do?